# Workflow and icon status

Tags: icons, workflow, status

I'm designing a new web app for my company. This web app allows the users to check some orders. For each order, we envisage to have the following status :

### [image: status icons list]

I wonder which icon we should use to illustrate the "checked" and "executed" status. 
In this case, do you think we should not use icons but only wordings in order to not create confusion ?
Is there any icons reference to apply ?

As we design many web applications, this need will often be encountered so I would like to set it up as a standard. This could favor the learning by experienced users.

Thank you

Answer (score 2):

I would say using the word "checked" is complicating things as the associated icon needs to be the same as "executed", which is confusing for the users.

I would suggest changing "checked" to "reviewed" as it implies the same thing. Change the icon to something such as the one below and leave the green and the larger check mark to the final stage of the process.

[image]

Answer (score 2):

As "checked" is technically one of the 2-part positive "approved" states (checked and executed), I would recommend the following to suggest this:

[image: Checked / Executed]

I would also strongly advise taking onboard the point about changing the terminology to "reviewed" - it is a more specific description of the action taken (anyone upvoting this should also upvote the original answer for that point as well).